# Fill missing data points in `GROUP_CONCAT`

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, group-concatenation

I need to generate data to build some charts.
The current results have missing data points and I'd like them to fill them with `0`'s.

Data is stored in MySQL 8. [Simplified data sample & query fiddle here](https://gist.github.com/MadSputnik/f9c2b4a349f0c88b37b7f72f63423b98).

The query I currently have is

```
SELECT
    currency,
    GROUP_CONCAT(volume) AS volume
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE(t.created_at) AS created_at,
        t.currency AS currency,
        SUM(t.amount) AS volume
    FROM
        transactions AS t
    WHERE (t.created_at BETWEEN @start AND @end)
    GROUP BY
        created_at,
        currency
    ORDER BY
        created_at,
        currency) r
GROUP BY
    currency
```

which creates this result set:

| currency | volume |
| --- | --- |
| AUD | 27553.52,13395.20,18349.51,3773.29,... |
| BRL | 272.45,... |
| CAD | 14738.08,7372.58,5926.08,7877.14,... |
| CHF | 320.00,27.00,47.00,27.00,... |
| EUR | 888.62,2806.27,4445.30,805.93,... |
| GBP | 48588.64,37266.79,27275.01,13981.08,... |
| MXN | 10.00,16298.00,1900.00,... |
| SEK | 497.00,497.00,1491.00,... |
| USD | 374660.85,347793.84,523608.81,839710.22,... |

Where I need help:

- How can I fill the mising data points with `0`?
- Let's assume the worst and at some point there are no transactions for any of the currencies for a day (or multiple days). How can I fill those missing data points?

I've read quite a few posts about `WITH RECURSIVE` and `calendar tables` but I can't wrap my head around it.

I'd appreciate any help/pointers. Thank you!

#### Update 1

@Akina's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/297384/36760) basically does what I asked for (thank you!) **but**: the query takes *ages* to complete.

The `transactions` table currently holds ~4m rows of data. A monthly resultset averages to roughly ~270k rows. Amogst others, there are indexes on `currency`, `created_at` and a compound index for `created_at,currency`.

#### Update 2

Something is off with my indexes. If I
`LEFT JOIN transactions AS t FORCE INDEX(created_at) ...`
then the query completes in ~15s, regardless if I set the date range to a month or 6 months.

Comment: `ORDER BY` in subquery/CTE without LIMIT makes no sense - it may be ignored in outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE  -- calendar generation needs in recuirsion

-- generate calendar, DATE() performs parameter checking additionally

calendar AS ( SELECT DATE(@start) created_at
              UNION ALL
              SELECT created_at + INTERVAL 1 DAY
              FROM calendar
              WHERE created_at < DATE(@end) ),

-- collect currencies list
              
currencies AS ( SELECT DISTINCT currency
                FROM transactions ),

-- gather daily data for all dates and all currencies
-- replace NULLs for the dates where there is no data with zeroz

daily AS ( SELECT ca.created_at AS created_at,  
                  cu.currency AS currency,  
                  COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS volume
           FROM calendar ca
           CROSS JOIN currencies cu
           LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON ca.created_at = DATE(t.created_at)
                                      AND cu.currency = t.currency
           GROUP BY ca.created_at, cu.currency )

-- get final data, aggregated data is sorted

SELECT currency, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(volume ORDER BY created_at) AS volume
FROM daily
GROUP BY currency;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96b9434f665ea819c1fc2be225c403d4

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this results in the same data set. Additionally the query now takes 10+ seconds instead of ~1.

Comment: @MadSputnik Fixed. Check. Additionally - do not forget about the setting which limits GROUP_CONCAT() output length...

Comment: The query does give the correct results BUT: querying a single day takes ~50s (~7,500 rows), querying a month takes ~970s (~175,000 rows). Can this be improved? (my query above takes ~70ms for a day, ~2.5s for a month)

Comment: @MadSputnik *Can this be improved?* Of course. 1) Create currencies list as separate table and use it instead of CTE. 2) Generate dates list as separate (temporary) table and use it instead of CTE. 3) Add generated column for `created_at_date DATE AS (DATE(t.created_at)) VIRTUAL` and use it for joining (index by `created_at_date, currency, amount`).

Comment: Still takes way too long. :(

Comment: @MadSputnik Check execution plan - it can show what is the problematic point... maybe create another question even.

Comment: `ERROR 3636 (HY000): Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value` -- There's gotta be a better way!

Comment: @RickJames Add an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Calendar table is just table holding all desired values, for your exaple it would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (Currency char(3));

INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('AUD');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('BRL');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('CAD');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('CHF');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('EUR');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('GBP');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('MXN');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('SEK');
INSERT INTO calendar (Currency) VALUES ('USD');
```

Then it's just the matter of correct joining those values, so your updated query would look like:

```
-- Query

SET @start = '2021-07-01 00:00:00';
SET @end = '2021-08-01 00:00:00';

SELECT
    c.Currency,
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(volume), 0) AS volume
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE(t.created_at) AS created_at,
        t.currency AS currency,
        SUM(t.amount) AS volume
    FROM
        transactions AS t
    WHERE (t.created_at BETWEEN @start AND @end)
    GROUP BY
        created_at,
        currency
    ORDER BY
        created_at,
        currency) r
RIGHT JOIN calendar c on r.currency = c.Currency
GROUP BY
    c.Currency;
```

NOTE: you might want to delete `calendar` table after all or just use temporary table :)

[Here's fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eR9nqZ7uwtaANECBPnjuxv/0)

Comment: See sample data - none row contains NULL.

Comment: @Akina Showed data is RESULT , not data OP is talking about.

Comment: Please look 3rd line of the question text ("Data is stored in MySQL 8. Simplified data sample & query fiddle here.") and follow by the link.

Comment: @Akina Oh, thank you so much for that ! Rewritten my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

To get "missing" date you have to generate a date table with all dates and then join it to the original tabale.

There are many possibilities to do that, i choose, one that works also in mysql 5.x

When you have more data, there will be less 0.00

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
>   `id` bigint unsigned  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `currency` char(3) NOT NULL,
>   `amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
>   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
>
> -- Sample data
>
> INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `currency`, `amount`, `created_at`) VALUES
> (1, 'AUD', 42.00, '2021-07-25 07:47:54'),
> (2, 'CHF', 43.00, '2021-07-25 07:47:54'),
> (3, 'BRL', 82.00, '2021-07-25 07:47:54'),
> (4, 'AUD', 89.00, '2021-07-26 07:47:54'),
> (5, 'CHF', 99.00, '2021-07-26 07:47:54'),
> (6, 'BRL', 40.00, '2021-07-26 07:47:54'),
> (7, 'SEK', 74.00, '2021-07-26 07:47:54'),
> (8, 'AUD', 61.00, '2021-07-27 07:47:54'),
> (9, 'CHF', 75.00, '2021-07-27 07:47:54'),
> (10, 'BRL', 90.00, '2021-07-27 07:47:54'),
> (11, 'MXN', 35.00, '2021-07-27 07:47:54'),
> (12, 'AUD', 76.00, '2021-07-28 07:47:54'),
> (13, 'CHF', 86.00, '2021-07-28 07:47:54'),
> (14, 'BRL', 14.00, '2021-07-28 07:47:54'),
> (15, 'USD', 70.00, '2021-07-28 07:47:54');
>
> -- Query
>
> SET @start = '2021-07-01 00:00:00';
> SET @end = '2021-08-01 00:00:00';
>
> SELECT
>     currency,
>     GROUP_CONCAT(volume) AS volume
> FROM (
>     SELECT
>         DATE(t.created_at) AS created_at,
>         t.currency AS currency,
>         SUM(t.amount) AS volume
>     FROM
>         transactions AS t
>     WHERE (t.created_at BETWEEN @start AND @end)
>     GROUP BY
>         created_at,
>         currency
>     ORDER BY
>         created_at,
>         currency) r
> GROUP BY
>     currency;
> ```
>
> ```
> currency | volume                 
> :------- | :----------------------
> AUD      | 42.00,89.00,61.00,76.00
> BRL      | 82.00,40.00,90.00,14.00
> CHF      | 43.00,99.00,75.00,86.00
> MXN      | 35.00                  
> SEK      | 74.00                  
> USD      | 70.00
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     currency,
>     GROUP_CONCAT(volume ORDER BY gen_date ASC) AS volume
> FROM (
> SELECT t3.gen_date,t3.currency,IFNULL(volume,0) volume
> FROM
>     (SELECT
>         DATE(t.created_at) AS created_at,
>         t.currency AS currency,
>         SUM(t.amount) AS volume
>     FROM
>         transactions AS t
>     WHERE (t.created_at BETWEEN @start AND @end)
>     GROUP BY
>         created_at,
>         currency
>     ORDER BY
>         created_at,
>         currency) t1
>         RIGHT JOIN
>         (SELECT `currency`, gen_date
> FROM
> (SELECT DISTINCT  `currency` FROM transactions) t1  CROSS  JOIN 
> (select gen_date from 
> (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date from
>  (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
>  (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
>  (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
>  (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
>  (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
> where gen_date between @start and @end) t2) t3 ON t3.gen_date = t1.created_at and t3.currency = t1.currency) t4
> GROUP BY  currency
> ```
>
> ```
> currency | volume                                                                                                                                                        
> :------- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AUD      | 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,42.00,89.00,61.00,76.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
> BRL      | 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,82.00,40.00,90.00,14.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
> CHF      | 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,43.00,99.00,75.00,86.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
> MXN      | 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,35.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00   
> SEK      | 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,74.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00   
> USD      | 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,70.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca4ff3bbd2142e13dfde9c631a771bcc)*

Comment: Thank you. I prefer @Akina's `WITH RECURSIVE` approach.

Comment: i didn't see mysql 8 at least i don't remeber, maybe it is still helpfull

Comment: It is! Always good to see different approaches to solve a problem!